# How can I prevent users of my compiled library from viewing the code?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have created a dll and accessing on an application. When I debug the application can go into the dll code and read the code. I want to prevent this debugging of dll functions for the security purpose. How can it be done? I would also like to prevent people from viewing the code altogether.

Comment: *Why*? To hide your code? Then hindering debugging isn't going to help much. Your "user" will just need a decent decompilation tool like Reflector or dotPeek.

Comment: I want to give that dll to client so that they can access only functions and not viewing code

Comment: Then what you want *is* obfuscation. @IvanL has provided a keyword for you to perform research on.

Comment: @J.Steen Sorry if the answer was short but I don't see much use in linking wikipedia pages or product pages of obfuscators... The term should be enough to find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent debugging, open your DLL project properties, under Advanced Compile Options, "Generate Debug Info" must be set to 'None'. And that's it.

Steps:
Right click on project -> Properties -> 'Build' tab -> 'Advanced' button -> Debug Info dropdown value set to 'None'.

Comment: Or just don't give the .pdb files to the customers... It's useful to still generate them for internal debugging purposes.

Answer (score 4):

Obfuscation is what you're most likely looking for.

Comment: I do not want user to debug any dll functions.

Comment: +1 For understanding the *real* and *underlying* requirement of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use obfuscation software like [Eazfuscator.NET](http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net).

That will prevent decompilation tools like ILSpy, dotPeek, etc. from showing your code in an easily understandable manner.

Comment: @ogggre: thanks for the edit, it went commercial since my answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/13675182/750216